# WordPress front page (homepage) fails to redirect when static front page is set

Tags: wordpress, redirect, static, wordpress-theming

I have configured WordPress to display a static front page as described here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_SubPanel#Reading_Settings

When I save changes and try to visit my front page, my browser displays the following error:
"The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

[image: https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2791/4443154597_86d20d57d4.jpg]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2791/4443154597_86d20d57d4.jpg))</sub>

Changing cookies settings does not remedy the situation.

I'm using the theme Constructor ([http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/constructor](https://wordpress.org/themes/constructor/)), which I suspect may be contributing to the problem.

How can I make WordPress properly display my front page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a page called home or whatever, go to

```
**Admin->Settings->Reading**
```

Change the......

> Front page displays
>   1. **Your latest posts**
>   2. **A Static Page**
>   Select Static Page and from the dropdown select your newley created home/page.

if its not redirecting check your **permalink settings**...set it to default.
Check the homepage is working, re-apply any permalink settings you had..

If the page is still redirecting in a away it will never complete, then try opening your .htaccess file in the root of your wordpress site, delete anything inside and save it,

Again check your homepage... if its still not working, then it's def; down to your theme you are using, if there are particular theme templates for the homepage then that may be the cause.. no time to check the template myself just now, (maybe later)..

You could check the

```
admin->edit-page
```

you should see all your loaded pages on the site, 
hover over the homepage listing and click "**Quick Edit**" onm the right hand side, have a look and check the template drop down menu for any homepage specific template that needs applied to that particular page, then click update and re-check the homepage status now.

Comment: It turns out the problem was caused by a template from the designer we hired to do our web design. It took me so long to approve this answer because you mention the template only after you describe a solution that I already rule out and which I described having ruled out in my original question.

Comment: I tried the above and it worked fine after setting permalink to plain. But the issue now is that whenever i change the permalink back to post type then the page goes back to "not redirecting properly" error

Answer (score 0):

> "The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

this problem happening when you redirect to a page who redirect you back. and it create indefinite loop of redirecting. So, the browser will trap and confuse and produce such error. Read you code again

maybe you need contact the theme author